# UNIX C "reverse mmap": mapping address space to disk without actually writing it

Tags: c, unix, mmap

In my program, I generate some files, write it to disk, and then feed it to a second program, which again reads it from disk, in my parent application. I delete these files right after the second program has finished execution.

I was wondering whether there was something like a "reverse mmap" that would make an address space accessible for another program via the file system.
I could then "map" my address space to the filesystem, and program B could read it from there, thinking of it as regular files.

Any pointers?

Comment: That of course would work, but would also be far more code than a simple "reverse-mmap-call" would

Comment: Is the second program a child of the first?

Comment: yes. I also would not mind having the file only be accessible by the child. I cannot change the child however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System V shared memory is what you're looking for. See the `shmat`, `shmdt`, `shmget`, and related syscalls. But note that, like `mmap`'ing a file, this does not provide a simple `read()`/`write()` interface. It is potentially more performant but is also considerably more complicated. I've used SysV shared memory many times. It requires mutexes, either embedded in the shared memory or the SysV equivalent (see the `semget` and `semop` syscalls).

Answer (score 1):

> make an address space accessible for another program via the file system

Although there is technically a way to do exactly this via `/proc`, it's a terrible idea for this purpose so I won't go into details.

What you can do is to use `shm_open` to create (and map, and write to) a POSIX named shared memory object, which can then be similarly opened (and mapped, and read from) in another process. The path name must begin with `/` to be portably shareable like this.

This shared memory object isn't technically a file: although it will be backed by a `tmpfs` file at least on Linux, it won't be written to any disk except perhaps due to paging.

This *does* require the child process to know it's being given a shared memory segment name, unless you just pass the `tmpfs` pathname (eg, `/dev/shm/pathname` on Linux).